# Slider will change backlight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to make a kind of brightness option panel. After typing this code:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];

[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:string];
```

I got the following error:

```
Sending 'NSString *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')
```

Why does this code not working?

Comment: That error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because the `brightness` property is not a `NSString`, it is a `CGFloat`. Try:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:slider.value];
```

Comment: haha, I think to hard.. That worked! But when I change the slider the backlight doesn't change it will stay at 0.5

Comment: @user1883396 Is the code you're using in an IBAction linked to the slider's "value changed" action?

Comment: Have you set the maximum and minimum values of the slider? On another note, it looks like you're way ahead of yourself here - I suggest you read upon this area more, take a look at some tutorials on Objective-C/Cocoa-Touch - you'll save a lot more time and understand everything a lot better, enough to figure out at least what these errors mean.

Comment: @0x7fffffff No got it in the ViewDidLoad. But I maked an IBAction with value changed and it is working now! :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sooper i'm a beginner, watching tutorials now ;) thanks for the answers!

Comment: This is strange. When i leave my application on backlight brightness 1.0 the brightness stays. How to release it? So it goes back on the usual brightness what you have setup in the settings?